# Create service from command

Tags: centos, rhel, init.d

I have following command which I try to setup to run on startup:

```
su -l hive -c "nohup hive --service metastore > /var/log/hive/hive.out 2> /var/log/hive/hive.log   &"
```

I was thinking about creating service from this command, but I cannot achieve working code. 
Mine `start` function form init.d scripts looks like following:

```
DAEMON="hive-metastore"
DESC="hive metastore service"
EXEC_PATH="/usr/lib/hive/bin/hive"
SVC_USER="hive"
DAEMON_FLAGS="datanode"
PIDFILE="/var/run/hive/hive.pid"
LOCKDIR="/var/lock/subsys"
LOCKFILE="$LOCKDIR/hive"

install -d -m 0755 -o hive -g hive /var/run/hive 1>/dev/null 2>&1 || :
[ -d "$LOCKDIR" ] || install -d -m 0755 $LOCKDIR 1>/dev/null 2>&1 || :
start() {
  [ -x $EXEC_PATH ] || exit $ERROR_PROGRAM_NOT_INSTALLED
  log_success_msg "Starting ${DESC}: "

  su -s /bin/bash $TARGET_USER -c " $EXEC_PATH --service metastore > /var/log/hive/hive.out 2> /var/log/hive/hive.log &"

  # Some processes are slow to start
  sleep $SLEEP_TIME
  checkstatusofproc
  RETVAL=$?

  [ $RETVAL -eq $RETVAL_SUCCESS ] && touch $LOCKFILE
  return $RETVAL
}
```

Comment: What wasn't working with this? Where exactly are you getting tripped up?

Comment: Please clarify the exact problem. Does it not run? Run at the wrong time? Produce wrong results? No results? Any error messages? Why are you using nohup here?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the simplest way to get that command to run at system startup is:

```
echo 'su -l hive -c "nohup hive --service metastore > /var/log/hive/hive.out 2> /var/log/hive/hive.log   &"' >> /etc/rc.local
```

In terms of `/etc/init.d`, the answer is...it depends.  With sysvinit, /etc/init.d/hive only has to look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
su -l hive -c "nohup hive --service metastore > /var/log/hive/hive.out 2> /var/log/hive/hive.log   &"
```

With a simple `chmod 755 /etc/init.d/hive`, one can add this script to system startup by adding a couple of links:

```
cd /etc/rc3.d
ln -s ../init.d/hive S99hive
cd /etc/rc5.d
ln -s ../init.d/hive S99hive
```

Now, if we would prefer to use `chkconfig` to start the service, we would have the script `/etc/init.d/hive` look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# chkconfig: 2345 99 99
# Description: hive service
su -l hive -c "nohup hive --service metastore > /var/log/hive/hive.out 2> /var/log/hive/hive.log   &"
```

Then, to add it at system startup time:

```
chkconfig --add hive
```

If using a distro with a different init, such as upstart or systemd, the way to get a service to start at system bootup is different.  For example, systemd: http://www.certdepot.net/rhel7-get-started-systemd/

Comment: With chkconfig --add you have to add special comments to the top of your script so that chkconfig will know what runlevels to start/kill your "service". Look at any pre-existing script for an example of what these comments look like.

Comment: I was wondering about that.  I will edit this post with the appropriate comments.

Comment: Yeah those comments are like some secret feature that is never discussed anywhere that I've seen, you're just suppose to know about them after screwing around with that tool for 10 years 8-)

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Operations_Network/2.1/html/JON_Server_Guide/JON_Server-Running_Server-Running_Unix.html

Comment: The reason I like being a part of this community is because I am learning new ways to solve problems in Linux system, such as the very useful `chkconfig` tool.  I will have to test making scripts before I feel comfortable answering questions with chkconfig examples.

Comment: Yeah this site is very unusual compared to the other SE sites I've found. Most everyone is very generous to help and everyone genuinely wants to find the most concise A's to Q's. I'd keep answering anything you can. The thing w/ A'ing is that you get better the more you do it, and I constantly learn new things that I never would've thought to look for or try.

Comment: I just added a `chkconfig` example to the answer and a pointer to a `systemd` howto.